# Make folders unreadable for everyone but sudo users and owners

Tags: permissions

What I am trying to do:
I am managing a class server and I want to allow all of the users to save their work to their home directories. I do not want users to be able to view other users home directories except for sudo users.

I believe this can be accomplished by doing the following

```
chmod -R 700 user1/
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Better option would be `750`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo chmod 750 /home/$USER` so the files inside don't pick up those permission but stops non-owners from accessing `home` folders